# onLoad vs. onError: how to get both work together?

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onerror

I mask all urls in the body with a javascript, like

```js
    function mask() {
      var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/\./g, '"|"');
      }
    }
```

```html
<body onLoad="mask()"> 
<a href="https://example.com">link</a>
</body>
```

Then i want to unmask urls, but only in case there is a non-existing image in the page (onError), like

```js
function mask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/\./g, '"|"');
  }
}

function unmask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/"\|"/g, '.');
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="mask()">

<a href="https://example.com">link</a>
<br /><br />
<button onClick="unmask()">unmask</button>
<br /><br />
<img src="non-existing-image.gif" onError="unmask()"/>
 
</body>
```

This doesn't work. But if i use for unmasking something like button and `onClick`, unmasking works like expected: `onLoad` - urls masked, after click urls unmasked, like in example above.

**Q**: How do i unmask urls with `onError`?

Comment: seems that `onError` executes before `onLoad`

Comment: Yes, unmask() is executing itself before mask.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `onError` is executing before `onLoad`. As a work around, you could check if there are any missing images on the `load` event. If it is missing images, don't call `mask()` at all.

```js
function maskIfNoMissingImage() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var isMissingImage = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (!images[i].complete || typeof images[i].naturalWidth == "undefined" || images[i].naturalWidth == 0) {
      isMissingImage = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!isMissingImage) {
    mask();
  }
}


function mask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/\./g, '"|"');
  }
}

function unmask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/"\|"/g, '.');
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="maskIfNoMissingImage()">

  <a href="https://example.com">link</a>
  <br /><br />
  <button onClick="unmask()">unmask</button>
  <br /><br />
  <img src="non-existing-image.gif" />

</body>
```